# how to send media file to wcf rest json service and get string return response in json format

Tags: android, json, image, wcf, upload

***Please don't mark it as duplicate as I am fighting for many days and have already tried lots of examples but not able to solve and getting confuse.I am new to WCF and android also***
So I have created a WCF service with some get and post method like below

```
[OperationContract]
    [WebInvoke(Method = "POST",
       UriTemplate = "RegisterUser",
       BodyStyle = WebMessageBodyStyle.WrappedRequest,
       RequestFormat= WebMessageFormat.Json,
       ResponseFormat = WebMessageFormat.Json)]
    ResultSet RegisterUser(string EmailID, string Name,Stream profilepic, string Mobile, long IMEI);
```

I am calling this service method by android client as below

MainActivity.java

```
public void doneOnClick(View v) throws FileNotFoundException,
        InterruptedException, JSONException {
    // Toast toast = new Toast(this);
    // gets IMEI of device ID
    tm = (TelephonyManager) getSystemService(Context.TELEPHONY_SERVICE);
    imei = tm.getDeviceId();

    bMap = BitmapFactory.decodeFile(selectedImagePath);
    path = SaveImage.writeFileToInternalStorage(getApplicationContext(),
            bMap, "UserImage.png");

    name = nameV.getText().toString();
    mobile = mobileV.getText().toString();
    emailID = emailV.getText().toString();

    if (name.length() != 0 && mobile.length() != 0 && emailID.length() != 0
            && path.length() != 0) {
        SharedPreferences shared = getSharedPreferences(PREFS, 0);
        Editor editor = shared.edit();
        editor.putString("UserPicPath", path);
        editor.putString("UserName", name);
        editor.putString("UserMobile1", mobile);
        editor.putString("UserEmail", emailID);
        editor.putString("IMEI", imei);
        editor.commit();
    }

    JSONArray jsonarr = new JSONArray();

    JSONObject jsonObj = new JSONObject();
    jsonObj.put("emailID", emailID);
    jsonObj.put("name", name);
    jsonObj.put("mobile", mobile);
    jsonObj.put("imei", imei);
    jsonarr.put(jsonObj);
    servicemethodname = "RegisterUser";
    DownloadWebPageTask bcktask = new DownloadWebPageTask();
    bcktask.execute(servicemethodname, jsonarr);
}
```

and calling backgroundtask as

```
package com.example.wcfconsumer;

import java.io.BufferedReader;
import java.io.ByteArrayOutputStream;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.io.InputStream;
import java.io.InputStreamReader;
import java.io.UnsupportedEncodingException;

import org.apache.http.HttpEntity;
import org.apache.http.HttpResponse;

import org.apache.http.client.ClientProtocolException;
import org.apache.http.client.methods.HttpPost;
import org.apache.http.entity.StringEntity;
import org.apache.http.impl.client.DefaultHttpClient;
import org.json.JSONArray;

import android.graphics.Bitmap;
import android.os.AsyncTask;
import android.util.Base64;
import android.util.Log;

public class DownloadWebPageTask extends AsyncTask<Object, Integer, String> {

private final static String SERVICE_URI = "http://192.168.0.100:80/Service1.svc/";

protected void onPostExecute(String result) {
    MainActivity.emailV.setText(result);
}

@Override
protected String doInBackground(Object... params) {
    JSONArray jsonparams = (JSONArray) params[1];
    String methodname = params[0].toString();
    InputStream is;
    try {
        DefaultHttpClient httpClient = new DefaultHttpClient();
        HttpPost httpPost = new HttpPost(SERVICE_URI + methodname);
        StringEntity se = new StringEntity(jsonparams.toString(), "UTF-8");
        se.setContentType("application/json;charset=UTF-8");
        httpPost.setEntity(se);
        Log.e("Gerhard", jsonparams.toString());
        HttpResponse httpResponse = httpClient.execute(httpPost);
        HttpEntity httpEntity = httpResponse.getEntity();
        is = httpEntity.getContent();

        InputStreamReader i = new InputStreamReader(is);
        BufferedReader str = new BufferedReader(i);
        String msg = str.readLine();
        Log.e("Gerhard", msg);
        return msg;
    } catch (UnsupportedEncodingException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    } catch (ClientProtocolException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    } catch (IOException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
    return null;
}

private String convertToString(Bitmap image) {
    ByteArrayOutputStream bos = new ByteArrayOutputStream();
    image.compress(Bitmap.CompressFormat.JPEG, 100, bos);
    byte[] data = bos.toByteArray();
    String mediaString = Base64.encodeToString(data, Base64.URL_SAFE);
    return mediaString;
}
}
```

My question contains multiple part :
1. How to send Image file along with other datatypes to RegisterUser method and get reponse in json format?
2. Does same will work for video file as for the Image file?
3. I want to return customdatatype from service(in this case ResultSet), is there something special I need to do for it?

***Please don't mark it as duplicate as I have already tried lots of examples but not able to solve and getting confuse.***

Please help me!!!    Many Many Many Thanks In Advance.
Regards,
Sourabh

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To send a media file (or any arbitrary file, for that matter) to WCF, you need to have an operation where the only parameter *in the request body* is of type `Stream`. That means that you can have other parameters to the operation, but they need to be passed via the URI (using the `UriTemplate` property of the `[WebInvoke]` attribute) - see more information in the post at http://blogs.msdn.com/b/carlosfigueira/archive/2008/04/17/wcf-raw-programming-model-receiving-arbitrary-data.aspx.

In your example, you'd have something like the code below:

```
[OperationContract]
[WebInvoke(Method = "POST",
   UriTemplate = "RegisterUser?emailId={EmailID}&name={Name}&mobile={Mobile}&IMEI={IMEI}",
   BodyStyle = WebMessageBodyStyle.WrappedRequest,
   RequestFormat= WebMessageFormat.Json,
   ResponseFormat = WebMessageFormat.Json)]
ResultSet RegisterUser(string EmailID, string Name,Stream profilepic, string Mobile, long IMEI);
```

And in the client you'd not use JSON, but pass the non-file parameters in the request URI, and the file contents in the request body.

And for your other questions: yes, it would also work for video files (for any arbitrary data, for that matter); and no, you don't need to do anything special for the return type - it should just work.

Comment: Thanks for your reply!!! It helped me. I tried it without image(only url parameters) and it is working.<br/> but when I tried with image in request body it was not working. I am sure I am making some mistake in placing image in http post. here is my code i am using.

Comment: Please ignore above comment.
Thanks for your reply!!! I tried it without image then it is working.but when I tried with image in request body it was not working. here is my code i am using.
**MultipartEntity mpEntity = new MultipartEntity();
File file = new File(imagepath);
ContentBody cbFile = new FileBody(file, "image/jpeg");
mpEntity.addPart("image", cbFile);
httpPost.setEntity(mpEntity);**

please tell me how to send image in http request body. I get above code from other tutorials. if you can tell me exact coding with little explanation it would be more helpful.
Thanks & Regards,
Sourabh

Comment: You shouldn't use a `MultipartEntity` - use a `ByteArrayEntity` instead. The `Stream` parameter in the server will receive the bytes sent by the client, and you want to send the exact bytes from the file.